# Does an exchange server duplicate email data when a user forward it?

Tags: exchange-server

Say we have a user a@domain.com which sends an email to user b@domain.com. Then, user b@domain.com forward the email to c@domain.com and d@domain.com.

Giving that it was the same email, does the exchange server keeps 4 different copies of the email data or it simply points the users to the same email (only with different headers)?

if user b@domain.com adds a simple line (or more, it does not really matter), but keeps the older email data intact, does the exchange server keeps a revision history of that mail and sends only the delta, or it simply builds a whole new email for c@domain.com and d@domain.com?

Comment: Stack overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: It's a question regarding the programming model of an exchange server or any other mail related server, I don't care about the actual server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Giving that it was the same email, does the exchange server keeps 4 different copies of the email data or it simply points the users to the same email (only with different headers)?

Regardless of any of your specific requests, each email *sent* is a new email (all new header info etc, is all part of an email).  If you send 1 email to 30 people (all on the same exchange store) there is only 1 version of the complete email in the system and 30 links to the email for each of the 30 people.  Attachments are also stored this way.

> if user b@domain.com adds a simple line (or more, it does not really matter), but keeps the older email data intact, does the exchange server keeps a revision history of that mail and sends only the delta, or it simply builds a whole new email for c@domain.com and d@domain.com?

I'm not sure about revision history, but again any email sent is a *new* email and regardless of exchange stores, is sent in it's entirety.  If fordwarded email contains an attachment and the recipient is on the same exchange store, exchange will not duplicate the attachment.

(This question will most likely be moved to http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Thanks - I thought it works that way, but I wasn't sure.